# syntaxerror unexpected token ' :'

Tags: typescript, graphql

Why is there an unexpected token in my file?

#### My code

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql` 
  type Project {
    id: number
    name: String!
    description: String
  }
  type Query {
    # trouver tous les projects
    projects: [Project]
    # trouver un project
    getProjectById(projectId: ID):Project
  }
`;
let projects = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'The Awakening',
    description: 'Kate Chopin',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'City of Glass',
    description: 'Paul Auster',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'City of Glass',
    description: 'Paul Auster',
  }
];
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    projects: () => projects,
    getProjectById: (_: any, args: { projectId: number }) => projects.find((project) => project.id == args.projectId)
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  csrfPrevention: true,
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(`  Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

#### In my console

```
getProjectById: (_: any, args: { projectId: number }) => projects.find((project) => project.id == args.projectId)
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

Comment: Are you sure typescript is configured correctly? This is in a ts file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiair with Apollo, this parameter structure looks a bit weird though, shouldn't it be something like this?

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    projects: () => projects,
    getProjectById: (projectId: number) => projects.find(({id}) => id == projectId)
  }
};
```

This article might help you out (chapter 'Example'):
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find